# google analytics api filter error

Tags: api, analytics

This is specific to my AdWords script not sending the correct filter. It strips out extra zero's.

I am writing a script that accesses the Google Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API. 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/

About Filters:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/reference#filters

Everything is working great except that I can't get filters to work right.

Here is the filter I'm using.

```
var results = Analytics.Data.Mcf.get('ga:' + profileId, startDate, endDate, 'mcf:totalConversions', // List of all metrics to retrieve.
        {
            'dimensions': 'mcf:campaignPath',
            'filters': 'mcf:conversionType==Transaction;mcf:timeLagInDaysHistogram<=090,mcf:pathLengthInInteractionsHistogram>=000001'
        });
```

This gives me the error:

```
Invalid value 'mcf:timeLagInDaysHistogram<=90' for filters parameter. (line 12)
```

If I took out the Lag part it would give same error for Length.

The docs say that I need to use a padded zero string.

"The length of conversion paths in number of days. The value is a histogram across a range of possible values. Format is a 3-digit zero-padded string representing an integer. For example, time lag of 3 days is represented as "003"."
"The length of conversion paths in number of interactions. The value is a histogram across a range of possible values. Format is a 6-digit zero-padded string representing an integer. For example, path length of 4 is represented as "000004"."

It works just fine if I use == but as soon as I use something else it errors out.